# Tag synonym proposal: writing-systems -> language

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

Two tags are relevant here, [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and [written-material](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-material). Full tag wiki excerpts:

**language:** *For questions about the written or spoken language of a world.*

**written-material:** *For questions about written material itself. (Books, newspapers, etc.) For questions about writing systems, use [language].*

I'm proposing a tag synonym [writing-systems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems) to be synonymized to [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language). Doing so would likely mean that we don't need the second sentence in the *written-material* tag wiki excerpt, as a substring match on `writ` will show both.

Comment: So you don't want to change anything about the existing tags, just add a new one to be synonymous with [tag:language]? Because that does seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Exactly. Keep our current tags exactly as they are, add a synonym to make one of them more discoverable, and maybe edit out the then-largely-unnecessary pointer to the other tag in the wiki excerpt.

Comment: There have been no objections, so I went ahead and created the synonym. Great idea.